# How to Assign the Value to Apex from the Javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have used the below code.

Visualforce page code snippet:

```
<Script>
    //Window Load
    document.getElementById("Today_Date").value = "2014-02-02";
</Script>

<input type="date" value="{!myDate}" id="myDate"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!CallMyMethod}" value="End" >
```

The Date is visible, but It doesn't come to Apex.

```
public date myDate{ get; set; }

public PageReference CallMyMethod() {
    //I got null when use the myDate;
    return null;
}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You use HTML input tag, but you need [apex:inputText tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm) instead.

So, using it on [apex:form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_form.htm) you will be able to submit Data to controller. For filling inputText with value from JS you need to add ID attribute to input for accessing it JS selectors (parent components also needs an ID). Here is short example:

**Visualforce page**:

```
<apex:page controller="TextInputController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        Input Text <apex:inputText value="{!inputText}" id="testText"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveText}"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.testText}').value ='Test value';
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Page controler**:

```
public with sharing class TextInputController{
    public String inputText{get;set;}
    public PageReference saveText(){
        //process here text value
        System.debug(inputText);
        return null;
    }
}
```